# file_get_contents() always returns bool(false) while URL returns a value during recapctha V2 upgrade in PHP

Tags: php, recaptcha

I am currently updating recaptchalib.php to upgrade captcha from V1 to V2.
I have done the client integration successfully. But at the server side facing issues. In my below code snippet if I hit the URL directly in browser I either get 
"success" : false with "error-codes" as "timeout-or-duplicate" OR
"success" :true but in both the above cases file_get_contents() returns the value as bool(false). Ultimately, always I get the error as "reCaptcha not enetered correctly" .Please suggest why file_get_content() is always returning bool(false)? What correction can be done in code so that we get response in correct format and then do json_decode successfully i.e hit 'true' case .
Below is the code snippet

```
$postdata = http_build_query(
                 array(
                        'secret'    =>  $privkey,
                        'response' => $response,
                         'remoteip'  =>  $remoteip
                        )
                );
$url = 'https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify?'.$postdata;
print "URL is " . $url . "<br>";
$response = file_get_contents($url);

var_dump($response) ;

$responses = json_decode($response, true);

if($responses["success"] === TRUE){
    echo "true";
}else{
    echo "false";
}
```

Comment: Can you reproduce the issue with a simple call to cURL or wget? Also, if `file_get_contents()` fails, why is there a `json_decode()` call, is that really part of the minimal example (MCVE)? Lastly, please format your code, for PHP there are PSR-1 and PSR-2, after all you want to make it easy for others to read it.

Comment: Formatted the code as per the suggestion.

Comment: I tried with cURL but with that again var_dump displays null and we enter the false clause. Same issue..

Comment: I meant the `curl` or `wget` executable on the commandline.

Comment: yes I tried the same.

Answer (score 0):

For file_get_contents() to work, the URL that is passed must not conatin any special characters. To obtain the sanitized version of the URL, use urlencode() [as mentioned here.](http://php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php) Looks like your URL might have special characters (private key etc.).

Try this:

```
$url = 'https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify?'.$postdata;
$url = urlencode($url);    
$response = file_get_contents($url);
```

Comment: I tried with urlencode but got the same response bool(false) :(